# unable to loop over an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

i have created a component and getting the data from userReducer and maaping it to props , but in render method if i console the data(i.e; array of users) , i can see the data in console but when i pass the data to a function and try to loop over the array , i am getting below error

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

i am not understanding did i make any mistake.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import * as userActions from '../../actions/userActions'
class HomePage extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading :true
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        const {dispatch} = this.props
        dispatch(userActions.loadUsers());
    }
    renderData(data){
        debugger
        data.map(item=>{
            return (<div>
              <h1>{item.id}</h1>
            </div>)
        })
    }
    render() {
        // if(!this.props.usersReducer) return <p>Loading ....</p>
        return (
            <div>
                {console.log(this.props.userReducer.data)}
                {this.renderData(this.props.userReducer.data)} // if i comment this line i can see the users array in console but if i uncomment this line i am getting undefined in console for console.log(this.props.userReducer.data) too
            </div>
        );
    }
}    
HomePage.propTypes = {};
HomePage.defaultProps = {};    
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) =>
    ({
        userReducer : state.userReducer
    })
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomePage);
```

Comment: What is value of `this.props.userReducer.data`?

Comment: what is the reason you are returning a div?
I think there's some problem with the way it's translated

Comment: Try removing `debugger` and add the missing return to `renderData`

Comment: replace your line which is generating error with : `(this.props.userReducer)
  ? this.renderData(this.props.userReducer.data)
  : null`

Comment: Sorry about the assault of questions, but I'm pretty sure I know the issue. Can you show us your reducer for `userReducer`?

Answer (score 0):

Add a check if `userReducer.data` is available in `props` before calling `map` function on it.

```
renderData(data){
    return data.map(item=>{
        return (<div>
          <h1>{item.id}</h1>
        </div>)
    })
}

render() {
    // if(!this.props.usersReducer) return <p>Loading ....</p>
    const { userReducer: { data } } = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            {console.log("data ===== > ", data)}
            {data
              ? this.renderData(data)
              : (<p>Loading ....</p>)
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And also call dispatch `loadUsers()` before mounting the component

```
componentWillMount(){
    const {dispatch} = this.props
    dispatch(userActions.loadUsers());
}
```

Always check for the data before rendering. I would like to suggest implementing it when checking for the map.

```
renderData(data){
  if (!data) {
    return (<div>Loading user data...</div>);
  } else {
    data.map(item=>{
        return (<div>
          <h1>{item.id}</h1>
        </div>)
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Better to have this check inside render function. It will prevent executing `renderData` if `userReducer.data` is empty.